# Installing Nvidia drivers on new Centos Install - can't blacklist Nouveau

Tags: linux, centos, nvidia-graphics-card

Using the following instructions to install Nvidia drivers on a new Centos 7  + MATE install
https://linuxconfig.org/nvidia-geforce-driver-installation-on-centos-7-linux-64-bit

Attempting to blacklist nouveau by issuing the following command

```
sudo echo 'blacklist nouveau' >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

I get the following returned

```
bash: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf: Permission denied
```

Not sure why. I am logged in as admin as well.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting permission denied is because you are running two commands.
`sudo echo 'blacklist nouveau'` and `>> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Notice the second command isn't sudo anything. You are attempting to write to the file with your own user permissions. The correct way to write to a file as root using echo would be

```
echo 'blacklist nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# echo 'blacklist nouveau' >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

# indicates that you already log in as root. Try again when you already logged as a root by typing sudo su first.

Comment: Where are you getting the `#` from? It is not in the OP's question.